# Cant run cmd.exe from razor (C#) project in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, command-line, iis-7

I am trying to develop a C# project with the following technologies:

MVC3, Nhibernate, Pokein, Razor ... and a project phase I launch command line to backup the databases between two servers through:

```
   ExecuteCommand ("mysqldump-h @ip-u root-ppassword DB Table> C: \ \ DataFor113 \ \ dbtable.sql", 10);
```

and

```
  ExecuteCommand ("mysql-h @ip -u root-ppassword DB Table"<C: \ \ DataFor113 \ \ DBTable.sql", 10);
```

it works fine locally but in IIS7 server in a Windows 2008 R2 server that is not running the command.

after a little research I have found the two links:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1576133.aspx/1
and
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

I changed app pool with the identity application pool but still cmd not excutant value.

Answer (score 0):

Add security rights to `C:\` to application pool which is used by your application.

For more information, read http://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/

An advice: do not store database backup on `C:\`, just on second partition `D:\` or whatever.

If you select `D:\` as path where save the backup, perhaps is not needed to add security rights.

Comment: This is solved and the solution is to add the rights creatn and read for application pool iis7 :)